# Determine browser height & width to resize image to full screen

Tags: jquery, image, fullscreen

I am trying to use jquery to get the browser height and width and than to use that information to resize my image to fit that dimensions. I want the images to be full screen on each page whether it is viewed on a laptop or a large monitor. I have all my images at a standard width of 1280 dpi now.

To view what I have so far I have posted my code to my nyu account: http://i5.nyu.edu/~ejs426/

Comment: Well, that's handy...have you considered posting your code *here*, where *we* are? Incidentally, are you not concerned about the aspect ratio of your images?

Answer (score 6):

jQuery

```
var W = $(window).width(),
    H = $(window).height();

$('img').height(H).width(W);
```

On resize

```
function imgsize() {
    var W = $(window).width(),
        H = $(window).height();

    $('img').height(H).width(W);
}
$(window).bind('resize', function() { imgsize(); });
```

CSS

```
img {height: 100%; width: 100%;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The only problem I am having is on the img resize since my images are in an array. I also want them to maintain an aspect ratio. Suggestions?

This is how I have my images:


$(function(){
        var images = ['editorial/image1.jpg','editorial/image2.jpg','editorial/image3.jpg','editorial/image4.jpg','editorial/image5.jpg','editorial/image6.jpg','editorial/image7.jpg','editorial/image8.jpg'];

Answer (score 1):

This can be done purely with CSS. I suggest checking out this tutorial:

http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/

The code below represnts the super easy CSS3 way of doing things. The tutorial offers other alternatives as well.

```
html {
        background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used in the past, setting the default height and width then trying to calculate it by trying to retrieve the various viewport dimensions.

```
var myWidth = 800;
var myHeight = 600;

    if ($.browser.msie) {
        if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {

            myWidth = window.innerWidth;
            myHeight = window.innerHeight;

        }
        else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {

            //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode' 

            myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

        } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {

            //IE 4 compatible 

            myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;

        }
    }
    else {
        myWidth = $(window).width();
        myHeight = $(window).height();
    }
```